# reverse UndistortRectifyMap

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I'm making multicamera-stereo calibration program.

My idea is to rectify each pair of cameras separately.

For example: for given 3 cameras I compute undistortion and rectification maps (using `stereoRectify()` and `initUndistortRectifyMap()`) separately for {camera[1] and camera[2]}, {camera[2] and camera[3]} and {camera[1] and camera[3]}.

Using `remap()`, I can transform any original image (from, lets say, camera[1]) to one of two different rectified images: rectified[1][2] and rectified[1][3].

Now, also using `remap()`, for any point from that original image, I can compute its new coordinates separately in rectified[1][2] and rectified[1][3] images.

It works well, but now I need to compute these coordinates in opposite direction: for any point from any of rectified images I need to find its original coordinates in its original image.

How can I do this?

Comment: I already found and idea how to do it: I need to use `undistortPoints` with inverted matrices P and R as parameters.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376649/how-do-you-redistort-a-point/63408201#63408201