# How do you redistort a point?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a distorted image on which I use `Cv2.Undistort()` which straightens it out. After this I find some points in the image. I need to get the location of those points in the distorted image.

I have tried `Cv2.ProjectPoints()` but failed to get appropriate coordinates. They were outside the bounds of the image.

This is how I went about doing this:

```
List<float> arr = new List<float>();
foreach (var i in points)
{
    arr.Add(i.X);
    arr.Add(i.Y);
    arr.Add(0);
}
Mat pointArr = new Mat(3, points.Count, MatType.CV_32FC1, arr.ToArray());
float[] rotArr = {  1, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 1};

float[] transArr = { 0, 0, 0 };

Mat rot = new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_32F, rotArr);
Mat trans = new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_32F, transArr);


Cv2.ProjectPoints(pointArr, rot, trans, camMatrix, dist, outputPoints);
List<Point2f> point2Fs = new List<Point2f>();
var lngt = outputPoints.Rows * outputPoints.Cols * outputPoints.Channels();
var matarr = new List<float>();
for (int i = 0; i < outputPoints.Rows; i++)
{
    point2Fs.Add(new Point2f(outputPoints.ExtractChannel(0).At<float>(0, i), outputPoints.ExtractChannel(1).At<float>(0, i)));
}
```

*points - the points in the undistorted image I want to find in the original*

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse of OpenCV projectPoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140150/reverse-of-opencv-projectpoints)

Comment: No. I do not have the real world coordinates of the points I am trying to find. I have pixel coordinates of the points in undistorted image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using 2nd option proposed by [Milo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755482/milo). I have rewritten the project point method without the rotation and translation part and starting the equation path from x' and y', where:

```
x' = (x_u - c_x) / f_x
y' = (y_u - c_y) / f_y
```

Then I applied the rest of the provided equations.

[image]

Here is the source code:

```
Point2f DistortPoint(Point2f point)
{
   var tempPt = new Point2f((point.X-intr.cx)/intr.fx, (point.Y-intr.cy)/intr.fy);
   var r2 = Math.Pow(tempPt.X, 2) + Math.Pow(tempPt.Y, 2);
   var xtmp = tempPt.X * ((1 + intr.k1 * r2 + intr.k2 * Math.Pow(r2, 2) + intr.k3 * Math.Pow(r2, 3)) /
                (1 + intr.k4 * r2 + intr.k5 * Math.Pow(r2, 2) + intr.k6 * Math.Pow(r2, 3))) + 2 * intr.p1 * tempPt.X * tempPt.Y + intr.p2 * (r2 + 2 * Math.Pow(tempPt.X, 2));
   var ytmp = tempPt.Y * ((1 + intr.k1 * r2 + intr.k2 * Math.Pow(r2, 2) + intr.k3 * Math.Pow(r2, 3)) /
                (1 + intr.k4 * r2 + intr.k5 * Math.Pow(r2, 2) + intr.k6 * Math.Pow(r2, 3))) + 2 * intr.p2 * tempPt.X * tempPt.Y + intr.p1 * (r2 + 2 * Math.Pow(tempPt.Y, 2));
   return new Point2f((float)(intr.fx * xtmp + intr.cx), (float)(intr.fy * ytmp + intr.cy));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't provide a function to do directly what you want, which is to apply the distortion coefficients to undistorted 2D points. You can:

**Option 1**

You are on the right track using projectPoints(). The trick to understand how this can work is that a point in the undistorted image "lives" in the image plane, which looks like this (picture from https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html):

[image]

Where the image plane is located at *f* (focal distance) from the origin and *x* and *y*  coordinates are relative to *c<sub>x</sub>* and *c<sub>y</sub>*.

What you have to do is to build your 3D points (x,y,z) from the undistorted 2D points (x<sub>u</sub>, y<sub>u</sub>) like this:

```
x = (x_u - c_x) / f_x
y = (y_u - c_y) / f_y
z = 1
```

Instead of using (x<sub>u</sub>, y<sub>u</sub>, 0) as in your first *foreach* loop.

Then call projectPoints().

You are correctly using an identity rotation and 0 translation. f<sub>x</sub>, f<sub>y</sub>, c<sub>x</sub> and c<sub>y</sub>, are in cameraMatrix:

```
|f_x  0  c_x|
| 0  f_y c_y|
| 0   0   1 |
```

**Option 2:**

You can directly apply the equations for the distortion (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html):

[image]

In the first step, you replace x' and y' by:

```
x' = (x_u - c_x) / f_x
y' = (y_u - c_y) / f_y
```

Then apply the rest of the equations. This is what projectPoints() does, without the rotation/translation part.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have tried the first option you suggested but got unacceptable values such as outside of the image bounds or negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by use indexing `mapx` and `mapy` returned from `cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap()`.

```
 x_distored = mapx[y_rectified, x_rectified]
 y_distored = mapy[y_rectified, x_rectified]
```

The limitation of this method is that the indices must be within the ranges.

I aslo have problem to use `Cv2.ProjectPoints()` to project rectified locations to distorted, even after normalizing `x_rectified` and `y_rectified`. My problem is unable to convert `R` and `T` (I got them from `cv2.stereoRectify()`. They are not all zeros.) to `rvec` and `tvec` required by `Cv2.ProjectPoints()` as input. If anyone has successful experience please share it, thanks!